# Mobile Devices: Get Location

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, geolocation, gps

I have a little problem, I want to show my user his location in one of my web applications on any mobile device (IPhone, IPad, Android phones and tablets, that kind of things).

I have asked Mr. Google for a while, but all I can find is some applications which shows me the coordinates or use those coordinates in a map application. But what I want is not to show my user his coordinates, which is pretty useless, I want to say: "Location: Berlin, Frankfurt or whatever" Not more, only the city in which he is. Don't ask why, I have got those requirements from someone else =)

Do you have any idea how I can achieve this? I already tried geoplugin.com, but it doesn't work for me. I get at least the country, but nothing more.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I forgot I already use Dojo 1.5 and JQuery Mobile 1.3.1 in my application

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/?hl=de).

In your case the [Reverse Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding) should be the right thing.